# Core Data is very slow on the old device such as iPhone4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

In my app, I have used simple core data structure. 
I call my server api and then store like 30 objects per request into `NSManagedObject`.  So that 30 managed objects during per cycle and then my tableView reloaded.

My code looks like this

```
//we have 30 entities here in "post_items"
for(NSDictionary *post in [d objectForKeyNotNull:@"post_items"])
    {
        NSNumber *itemId= [post objectForKeyNotNull:@"id"];
    if(itemId){


        Item *i = [[ChannelStore sharedStore] fetchItem:itemId];

        if(!i) i = [[ChannelStore sharedStore] createItem];

        [i readFromJSONDictionary:post];

        [_items addObject:i];


    }


}

-(Item*)createItem
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

return item;

}


   -(Item*)fetchItem:(NSNumber *)itemId;
{



NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];

// Create Predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"itemID", itemId];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:1];

// Execute Fetch Request
NSError *fetchError = nil;


NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
Item* item = nil;

if (!fetchError) {
    item = [result firstObject];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Error fetching data.");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", fetchError, fetchError.localizedDescription);
}


return item;
}
```

What make the process slow is because I have to fetch so check for existing Item first and then create new one if there is none. 
I know that I use only one MOC here. This result in UI blocking. But if we concern about speed here. I doubt implementing parent-child MOC would help. Because in parent-child . I will just have another MOC running on background but it is one MOC for 30 objects it should more or less take the same amount of times.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried searching all over but could not find a proper solution for this. Or maybe, I should not use Core Data for "Items" object at all ?

PS. I do not have performance problem in newer devices but just the old device that make my app looks very laggy and slow

Comment: you should have a background context. store the ids in memory to decide if there's a dupe rather than individual fetch each, or batch the request

Comment: You can speed thing up - on all devices - by minimising the number of calls you make.  Go get all 30 objects before you start checking for duplicates, and you only have one overhead of the fetch instead of 30.  It's also worth remembering that something which takes longer, but looks quicker - using background fetching and quickly updating the UI - gives a better user experience.  If you don't need all of the data returned before you start updating the display, then don't wait for it!  Go get the rest of the data in the background

Comment: @Russell Thanks, I finally sorted things out by doing only one fetch instead of 30 fetches. The app looks really fast now. However, one in a while , very randomly, the app will freeze for like 2-3 seconds. Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason for your slowness here is do to the number of fetch's that you are executing.  Each fetch request forces the core data stack to make a roundtrip all the way to disk, since you are doing this for *each* item you are importing, this results in a bottleneck for your importing implementation.  This bottleneck then results in a UI slowdown because it is happening on a main queue context.

The solution is to perform a single fetch to see which of the incoming objects you already have locally and which are new.

Once you have your local objects in memory, it is much faster to check that array than to use an `NSFetchRequest` each time.

Here is a WWDC video that addresses your exact problem: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-211/

Specifically they talk about implementing "Update or Insert" at around 14m into the video.

Comment: Thank you. I have finished watching the video as you suggested. Anyway, do you have a sample code for "Update or Insert" operation using NSEnumerator ? . I only saw a few line of code in the video but not the whole.

Comment: Never mind, I figured the solution out. Just use the SQL syntaxes such as %K in %@ . while %@ is nsarray

Comment: The app looks really fast now. However, one in a while , very randomly, the app will freeze for like 2-3 seconds. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Without seeing more of the code, I can't make any real calls there.  Your best bet is to check out some of the WWDC videos about profiling Core Data you should be able to find exactly what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your `NSFetchRequest`s by asking `CodeData` to fetch only the properties of interest (instead of fetching all the properties).

So, if you are interested only in `itemID`, then ask `CoreData` to check only `itemID`s

```
theFetchRequest.predicate = ...;
// you MUST set the predicate BEFORE using the next lines, otherwise your app will crash

theFetchRequest.includesSubentities = NO;
theFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"itemID"];
```

This helps **a lot** when your entities have

- attributes of `NSData` type
- relationships to other entities

---

A few days ago these two lines made my code 400 times faster...

Answer (score 0):

You must use privatequeueContext for fetching data from server & mainQueuCOntext for handling UI part. For more information please go through following links

[CoreDataConcurrency_Swift](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-concurrency--cms-25118)

[CoreDataCConcurrency_ObjC](https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/common-background-practices/)